# python - returning results based on max and min inputs from users

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Edited -- Using Pandas :)

I am trying to pull out flat_types available (for eg. one bedder, two bedder) based on user's inputs of the minimum and the maximum amount they are willing to spend. I cant seem to get any returns - am I doing this wrongly? Thanks!

```
# By Flat Price
min_flat_price = input ("Enter a minimum flat price: ")
max_flat_price = input ("Enter a maximum flat price: ")

def flat_price():
    dummy_df = df[[df['resale_price']>= min_flat_price] & df[['resale_price']>= max_flat_price]]
    return (dummy_df['flat_type'.values])
    #results_df = df.loc[df['resale_price'].isin([min_flat_price, max_flat_price])]
```

Comment: please edit to include which dataframe you're using (I suppose pandas, but I might be wrong) and the database structure (just the part needed for understanding what you're trying to do)

Comment: Yes, using pandas! :)

Comment: my first guess would be the `.values` in the return statement, should be outside square brackets

Comment: opps you are right about the square brackets but it's still not throwing the results :(

Comment: see the answer below, you have a `>` instead of `<` with the max

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to run your code to test but I see that there is a logic error in your conditional:

```py
df['resale_price']>= min_flat_price] & df[['resale_price']>= max_flat_price
```

should be:

```py
df['resale_price'] >= min_flat_price] & df[['resale_price'] <= max_flat_price
```

Also you should wrap this conditional in parenthesis instead of brackets. The updated code should be this:

```py
def flat_price():
    dummy_df = df[(df['resale_price'] >= min_flat_price] & df[['resale_price'] <= max_flat_price)]
    return dummy_df['flat_type']
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the logic error :) I am still unable to return the results though. Is it because I am not printing it?

Comment: If you're expecting the data to print out to the screen, then yes you should print the result of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly...

```py
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> flat = namedtuple("flat", ["title", "price"])
>>> flats = [
   flat(title="flat 1", price=200),
   flat(title="flat 2", price=20),
   flat(title="flat 3", price=2000000)
]
>>> # you have to adjust the code according to how your data is structured.
>>> minprice = 120
>>> maxprice = 1000
>>> #you can then use the filter function like so
>>> #python supports chained conditional operators     \/            \/
>>> affordableflats = list(filter(lambda flat: minprice < flat.price < maxprice, flats))
>>> affordableflats
[flat(title='flat 1', price=200)]
```

It would be nice if you included how your specific data structure is set up. Looking at your code, it looks like your prices are in string format, since you don't cast the input to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I managed to get this sorted

```
min_flat_price = float(input ("Enter a minimum flat price: "))
max_flat_price = float(input ("Enter a maximum flat price: "))

df['resale_price'] = df['resale_price'].astype(float) ## this is comparing the price against the input and ensuring that the type is correct. 

dummy_df = dummy_df[(dummy_df['resale_price'] >= min_flat_price) & (dummy_df['resale_price'] <= max_flat_price)]
dummy_df = dummy_df['flat_type'] #pulls out the flat_type in CSV file 
dummy_df = dummy_df.drop_duplicates() #drops duplicates 
print(dummy_df)
```